# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'. Django Admin

Tags: django, model, django-admin

Here is my model and my admin code. Whenever I create a group without a headman I've got this error when Im reaching Groups page in admin -'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'. What should I change?

```
@admin.register(Group)
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("descipline", "hours_to_take", 'link_to_curator', "link_to_headman")
    list_filter = ("descipline", "hours_to_take")
    search_fields = ("descipline__startswith", )
    list_display_links = ['link_to_curator', 'link_to_headman']

    def link_to_headman(self, obj):
        link = reverse("admin:students_student_change", args=[obj.headman.id])
        return format_html(u'<a href="%s">%s<a/>' % (link,obj.headman.last_name))

class Group(models.Model):
    descipline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    hours_to_take = models.IntegerField(default=32)
    headman = models.ForeignKey('students.Student',blank=True, null=True, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="headed_group")
    curator = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,)
```

Comment: your error is in the `link_to_headman` function : `link = reverse("admin:students_student_change", args=[obj.headman.id])` . This line suppose that the `headman` variable is always provided

Comment: Rvector's answer is correct. I want to add: If you want to prevent this just do: `if not obj.headman: return None` before that error line.

Comment: Thank you. It helped a lot. Couldn't actually figure out where the problem comes from.